# Using Angular2 in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, angular2

All

I need to develop a simple application in Angular2 which will run on SharePoint Online.

I have gone through all the articles relevant to be able to make a decision.

My Options are either, I will use SharePoint Add-in and configure it to use Angular2 in, or Create a page layout and reference my Angular2 app there.

My question is that if I use second option which is using angular in a page layout, how will I use sharepoint js library to do my development environment?

I want to do development without deploying it to SharePoint online to test. Once I am done with development, that is the point I would like to made deployment.

Could you point me to right direction please?
thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the modern SPFx stuff? See https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman No, not really. I have not developed Apps before for SP online. It looks like not suggested to be used in Prod environment as it is still in preview.  is this my only option?

Comment: No, you can go 'oldskool' with your two mentioned options, but Microsoft is churning out SPFx fast, latest Drop 6 is already available to first-release tenants, all Modern Experiences are built with it, so expect SPFx to be "In Production" within months

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman What if I develop it on premise(as it will be a simple app) and deploy it to site assets in the site collection in SP online? My problem is rapid development. Deploying to SP online is hell everytime,,

Comment: That's up to you how you seperate the MVC pattern. I develop with mock List data generated with http://www.json-generator.com/ Only touch SharePoint when I really need to interact with SharePoint, and those interactions are abstracted in our own 'Framework' as well.. so developing FOR SharePoint is 90% NOT using SharePoint. SPFx also has such a 'offline workbench' approach, but with SPFx you still develop SharePoint webParts... Our workbench helps us develop WebComponents; they run in WordPress or any headless CMS as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use angular-cli tool to develop angular (Angular 2, or Angular 4).
It generates really convenient and organized structure just by a single command

```
ng new [app name]
```

As far as sharepoint I dedicate **one directory inside documents** for Angular App.

When I'm ready to deploy, in console i generated build

```
ng build --prod
```

Then it outputs everything to your [directory]/dist
about 5 files, everything inside one of those file, the index.html are referenced. The only thing I had to change was the path to these references, because relative doesn't work.

So, inside the html.index, **instead of** src="./[filename]"  I **changed it to** src="[sharepoint link to file when you click on it]"